# Restructuring list with purrr

Tags: r, list, purrr

I have following problem when cleaning complicated list with R and purrr. Example will clear this one out.

Packages needed

```
library(jsonlite)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
```

Let's get example data from NHL json.

```
url <- c("https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/game/2017010002/feed/live", "https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/game/2017010005/feed/live")

data_list <- map(url, fromJSON)
```

This is pretty complicated list but in the end I would like to have `result` which is in the end. Main idea is that I want to have list column with tibble in it, but tibble is created from chosen vectors/columns from different parts of the list. Here is my failed try:

```
wrong <- tibble(
  gamepk = map_chr(data_list, c("gamePk"), .default = NA),
  home = map_chr(data_list, c("gameData", "teams", "home", "triCode"), .default = NA),
  away = map_chr(data_list, c("gameData", "teams", "away", "triCode"), .default = NA),
  test = list(tibble(event = map(data_list, c("liveData", "plays", "allPlays", "result", "event"), .default = NA),
                     x_cord = map(data_list, c("liveData", "plays", "allPlays", "coordinates", "x"), .default = NA),
                     y_cord = map(data_list, c("liveData", "plays", "allPlays", "coordinates", "y"), .default = NA)))
)

# A tibble: 2 x 4
  gamepk     home  away  test            
  <chr>      <chr> <chr> <list>          
1 2017010002 VAN   VGK   <tibble [2 x 3]>
2 2017010005 BUF   CAR   <tibble [2 x 3]>
```

Here is awkward way to do it and correct result.

```
result <- tibble(
  gamepk = map_chr(data_list, c("gamePk"), .default = NA),
  home = map_chr(data_list, c("gameData", "teams", "home", "triCode"), .default = NA),
  away = map_chr(data_list, c("gameData", "teams", "away", "triCode"), .default = NA))

test1 <- bind_cols(event = data_list[[1]]$liveData$plays$allPlays$result$event, 
          x_cord = data_list[[1]]$liveData$plays$allPlays$coordinates$x,
          y_cord = data_list[[1]]$liveData$plays$allPlays$coordinates$y)

test2 <- bind_cols(event = data_list[[2]]$liveData$plays$allPlays$result$event, 
                  x_cord = data_list[[2]]$liveData$plays$allPlays$coordinates$x,
                  y_cord = data_list[[2]]$liveData$plays$allPlays$coordinates$y)

result$test[1] <- list(test1)
result$test[2] <- list(test2)

result

# A tibble: 2 x 4
  gamepk     home  away  test              
  <chr>      <chr> <chr> <list>            
1 2017010002 VAN   VGK   <tibble [314 x 3]>
2 2017010005 BUF   CAR   <tibble [283 x 3]>
```

Comment: I get error tbl_vars can’t be used on list. I haven’t used those functions, so maybe I’m missing something

Comment: Once you make your nested list `test` in your first example (remove the `tibble` function from that line) you can pipe into `pmap` to go through the the elements of each nested list and return a `tibble`. So `test = list(event = map..., x_cord = ..., y_cord = ...) %>% pmap(tibble)`

Comment: Beautiful, post it as answer and will close this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building off of all the work you've already done, if you make `test` a list of lists you can pass it on to `pmap()` with `tibble()`.  This loops through each element of the nested lists simultaneously and "entibbles" it together, leaving you with a list of two tibbles.

The new line for `test` will look like:

```
test = list(event = map(data_list, c("liveData", "plays", "allPlays", "result", "event"), .default = NA),
                x_cord = map(data_list, c("liveData", "plays", "allPlays", "coordinates", "x"), .default = NA),
                y_cord = map(data_list, c("liveData", "plays", "allPlays", "coordinates", "y"), .default = NA)) %>% 
        pmap(tibble)
```

Combining that with what you already had gives the "right" output.

```
right <- tibble(
    gamepk = map_chr(data_list, c("gamePk"), .default = NA),
    home = map_chr(data_list, c("gameData", "teams", "home", "triCode"), .default = NA),
    away = map_chr(data_list, c("gameData", "teams", "away", "triCode"), .default = NA),
    test = list(event = map(data_list, c("liveData", "plays", "allPlays", "result", "event"), .default = NA),
                x_cord = map(data_list, c("liveData", "plays", "allPlays", "coordinates", "x"), .default = NA),
                y_cord = map(data_list, c("liveData", "plays", "allPlays", "coordinates", "y"), .default = NA)) %>% 
        pmap(tibble) )

right

# A tibble: 2 x 4
  gamepk     home  away  test              
  <chr>      <chr> <chr> <list>            
1 2017010002 VAN   VGK   <tibble [314 x 3]>
2 2017010005 BUF   CAR   <tibble [283 x 3]>
```